# Cannot parse XML with nested CDATA section

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am having a problem while parsing XML with nested CDATA section. The CDATA section is as below:

```
<![CDATA[*** some text

[ !  <![CDATA[some text]]>  ! ]

<![CDATA[some text]]>

]]>
```

When this type of data is appearing in an XML tag, it is giving an error while parsing the XML as there are two closing tags ]]>. Can anyone please suggest me what to do or what character should I escape to make this work? I am using Java1.8.

Comment: How are you parsing the XML? SAX, StAX, DOM, something else? Can you show us a minimal programm that generates this error?

Comment: Actually, some other application is parsing the XML and it is Oracle ESB. But even when I paste this in Notepad and try to beautify XML, it is showing that it is not a valid XML. It is working when I remove one ]]> end tag.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Nesting for an workaround.

Comment: @GyroGearless - Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having trouble parsing this input is that it isn't XML. You need to find out what program is generating this non-XML and fix it.

If you are generating XML, then whenever you create a text node that might contain the sequence `]]>` (whether or not this represents the end of a nested CDATA section) you need to escape it somehow. Many people take the path of least resistance and simply escape `>` as `&gt;` wherever it occurs, but technically this is needed only if the `>` is preceded by `]]`.